# Download all images from a website [not thumbnails] Python

Tags: python, image, search

I have a bunch of url stored in a list .
Iteratively I have to download all the images in the folder in original quality. Now I am able to download only thumbnails of everything in that site. As a part of project I need original quality Images . I am getting Images from google image search , that code I am showing here. But after a few iterations , it is downloading same images by retrieving same links .

```
import os
import sys
import time
from urllib import FancyURLopener
import urllib2
import simplejson
import time


# Define search term
searchTerm = "sachin"

# Replace spaces ' ' in search term for '%20' in order to comply with request
searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(' ','%20')


# Start FancyURLopener with defined version 
class MyOpener(FancyURLopener): 
version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'
myopener = MyOpener()

# Set count to 0
count= 0

for i in range(0,100):
# Notice that the start changes for each iteration in order to request a new set of    images for each loop
 url = ('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?' + 'v=1.0&q='+searchTerm+'&start='+str(i*10)+'&userip=MyIP')
 print url
 request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {'Referer': 'testing'})
 response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

# Get results using JSON
results = simplejson.load(response)
if results["responseStatus"] == 200:
    data = results['responseData']
    dataInfo = data['results']

# Iterate for each result and get unescaped url
for myUrl in dataInfo:
    count = count + 1
    my_url = myUrl['unescapedUrl']
    print my_url
    f = open("C:\\Sarath\\links.txt", "a")
    f.write(my_url+ "\n")
    myopener.retrieve(myUrl['unescapedUrl'],str(count)+'.jpg')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by _"it is downloading same images by retrieving same links"_ and what you think the origin of the problem is?  You will get better responses if you can isolate the problem you are having.

Comment: OP already has open question on this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718819/downloading-images-from-google-search-using-python-gives-error

Comment: Check the indenting in your code; is it showing identical to what you have in your code editor? As it currently appears, the blocks are in the wrong places.

Comment: @ChrisP - I will make it clear . first 20 images are different images of sachin . After that it download image 21,22,23(unique) and these three images are iteratively downloading. When I displayed the Links, I came to know that the system is following the same links after a specific time. that is why it is downloading same images . But the problem is I dont know , how to rectify it .